# Curious about how setTimeout() function works

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I will appreciate if you help me in understanding function `setTimeout()`. Please refer to the following piece of code:

```
function doLog() {
  console.log(111);
}

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(doLog());
  }, 4000)
});

promise.then(() => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('DONE');
  }, 3000);
})
```

It works perfectly; first I get `111` message in 4 seconds, then I get `DONE` message in 3 seconds after first message. Now I change this part of code (in my thoughts purpose was to make it shorter):

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve(doLog()), 4000)
});
```

**Problem description:** The code inside `resolve` gets executed immediately, while I expected it to be resolved in 4 seconds.

Ask for your help:

1. Why code inside `resolve` was executed immediately? As I believe delay 4000 was ignored, if yes then help me understand why?
2. How `function(){}` wrapper helps prevent `resolve()` not to be executed immediately?

I will really appreciate your help, and for all of you happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(doLog());
}, 4000)
```

The above code means "create a function with the text `() => { resolve(doLog()) }`, and pass it into `setTimeout` so my new function can run in 4 seconds. When it runs, call doLog, and pass its result into resolve.

```
setTimeout(resolve(doLog()), 4000)
```

The above code means "Call `doLog()` right now, and pass its result into `resolve`. Pass the result of `resolve` into `setTimeout` so that, if the result of `resolve()` happens to be a function, that function can run in 4 seconds" In reality the return value from resolve() is *not* a function, so nothing will happen after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, you are executing the `resolve` function immediately and only passing its return value to the timeout function: it generally returns `undefined` and not an invocable function, so `setTimeout` has nothing to call. Not good! You *could* do the following, which would call the `resolve` function after 4 seconds, but you wouldn't be able to pass arguments:

```
setTimeout(resolve, 4000);
```

So if you need to pass arguments, you have to wrap it in a surrounding function, to stop it from executing immediately (which happens whenever two braces follow a function name in the current scope):

```
setTimeout(() => { resolve(a, b, c); }, 4e3);
// 4e3 === 4000
```

The two code snippets that I've given above both send functions to `setTimeout` which are only invoked after 4 seconds. So you will generally want to use one of those two approaches.

However, if you were to immediately invoke the wrapping function, you would encounter exactly the same problem (of calling resolve straight away and returning `undefined` to `setTimeout`, since the wrapping function doesn't have a return value, rather than a function that can later be called):

```
setTimeout(() => { resolve(a, b, c); }(), 4e3);
```

So don't invoke your function when passing it to `setTimeout!

Unless and only unless it returns another function that you want to be invoked after the timeout, as below:

```
setTimeout((a, b, c) => {
    return () => { // this function will be called after 4 seconds
        resolve(a, b, c);
    };
}(1, 2, 3), 4e3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling a function immediately in set timeout function. If you use below code then also result will be printing after 4 sec.

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(doLog, 4000)
});
```

Notice: no parens.
It doesn't have anything to do with `function(){}`

When you are calling like:

```
setTimeout(resolve(doLog()), 4000)
```

You are actually calling the function itself, but when yo are calling like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
resolve(doLog());
 }, 4000)
```

You are creating a callback.